# In libgdx, how do I get input from the back button?

Tags: android, libgdx

For my game, I'd like the Android back button to take you to the pause menu, instead of minimizing the game. From what I've googled, I know I need to call

```
Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
```

But how do I actually check for the button press? input.isKeyDown(Keys.BACK) doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I solved the problem like this:

```
public class MyApplication implements ApplicationListener, InputProcessor {
   // !! Remember to override all other required methods !!
   ...

   @Override
   public void create() {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
        Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
        // rest of your stuff...
   }

   ...

   @Override
   public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        if(keycode == Keys.BACK){
           // Do your optional back button handling (show pause menu?)
        }
        return false;
   }

   ...
}
```

Not copypasta stuff but hopefully this helps you out. :)

Comment: I would rather do this in my Screen class, which would give me finer control

Comment: In case you want to handle it in Screens,
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/114972/handling-back-button-in-android-without-implementing-inputprocessor/114985#114985

Comment: 2022 use: Gdx.input.setCatchKey(Input.Keys.BACK, true)

Answer (score 31):

You can use Gdx.input.isKeyPressed method.

```
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.BACK)){
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: This is life savior. It's strange why InputProcessor is getting event for back "button" when that class is used for detecting keyboard - for desktop devices. It would be more logical to get this event in GestureListener class.
Not to mention that you can set only one InputProcessor.

Comment: @MilanG you can set multiple inputprocessors using a multiplexer, see example here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20048019/22194

Comment: In case you want to handle it in Screens,
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/114972/handling-back-button-in-android-without-implementing-inputprocessor/114985#114985

Comment: Make sure you use `isKeyJustPressed`, not `isKeyPressed`. Just trying it out on my Android, it would sometimes register twice with the latter, which is probably not desirable.

Answer (score 21):

First create an InputProcessor to handle the back key actions and then add it to a multiplexer so that other components still receive similar events.

```
      InputProcessor backProcessor = new InputAdapter() {
            @Override
            public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {

                if ((keycode == Keys.ESCAPE) || (keycode == Keys.BACK) )

                // Maybe perform other operations before exiting
                Gdx.app.exit();
                return false;
            }
        };


        InputMultiplexer multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer(mStage,
                backProcessor);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);
```

And enable catching the back key.

```
Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
```

That's all there is. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.BACK)** but if you want that Activity does not closes you can handle this as:

```
Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
```