# How to pause and resume in LibGDX using the back key?

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm creating a game using LibGDX. Now I have two problems.

First, I'm trying to catch back key so that the game will pause. I'm already calling the `Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true)` method in my `Game` class. Here is the code :

```
public class CvSGame extends Game {
    public Preferences prefs;

    @Override
    public void create() {  
        Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
        prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("game_pref");
        //setScreen(new SplashScreen(this));
        //setScreen(new HomeScreen(this));
        //setScreen(new GameScreen(this));
        GamePlay.initialized(this);
    }
}
```

`GamePlay.initialized` is a method to set the `Game` with a `GameScreen` which implements `Screen` and `InputProcessor`.

In the `GameScreen`, I already call `setInputProcessor`. The code for `GameScreen` is :

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor{
    CvSGame parent;


    public GameScreen(CvSGame pParent){
        parent = pParent;

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        if(keycode == Keys.BACK) {
            pauseGame();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }

    private void pauseGame(){
        GamePlay.gameState = GamePlay.PAUSED;
    }
}
```

I think, if the Back button on my Android device is pressed, it will call the `keyDown` method and  the method `pauseGame` will be called.

But, that's not happening. My game is exiting and the `keyDown` method is not called (I'm already try to log a message if method keyDown is called, but the message never appear).

The second problem I have is caused by pausing game with the method `pause()`. I think if the home button or the device receives a call, the method `pause` in `GameScreen` will be called. So, I think if I want to pause my game when the home button is pressed, I call the method `pauseGame` in method `pause`. And it works well. But the problem comes after I press back button so the game will quit. After the game quits and I try to start it again, my texture is not loaded.

By the way, currently I'm not using `AssetManager` but call a method to load assets in the constructor.

Comment: Please put separate questions in separate questions, it makes answers easier for folks to find in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is my understanding that you need to set your `InputProcessor` before calling `setCatchBackKey`.  You can fix this by changing your `GameScreen` constructor to:

```
public GameScreen(CvSGame pParent) {
    parent = pParent;
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
}
```

Related question: [In libgdx, how do I get input from the back button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223723/in-libgdx-how-do-i-get-input-from-the-back-button)

As for the texture not loading.  Make sure that when your game is destroyed (`dispose` function) that you're unloading all of your textures and disposing of them.  When your game is recreated, be sure to load them all again.

All of the classes listed [here](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/MemoryManagment) need to be disposed of manually or they can cause leaks.  In regards to textures, you can run into problems loading textures without first disposing of your older copies first.

Comment: Thanks, the first problem is solved now. For the second problem, I haven't try it yet, but I will change my code according to your advice.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case (invoking a `pause` method on back being pressed), you should not need to do anything special to catch the Back key.  Libgdx will invoke the `pause` method on your registered `ApplicationListener`.  See the [`ApplicationListener.pause()` javadoc](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/ApplicationListener.html#pause%28%29) which says:

> Called when the Application is paused. An Application is paused before it is destroyed, when a user pressed the Home button on Android or an incoming call happened. On the desktop this will only be called immediately before dispose() is called.

The `Game` `ApplicationListener` will automatically forward `pause` to the current `Screen`, even.

Answer (score 0):

You implement `InputProcessor` on your class right? And also, as @MCeley said that you should put this code in order:

```java
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
```

Also, at the `pauseMenu()` method, add a Boolean parameter, a good old flag like this:

```java
private void pauseGame(boolean isPaused){
    if(isPaused) {
        GamePlay.gameState = GamePlay.PAUSED;
    } else {
        GamePlay.gameState = GamePlay.UNPAUSED;
    }
}
```

Add the boolean value as flag and field in the `GameScreen` class. Remember, flagging is like a marker and it's a better way to counter or reverse it. Before accepting my answer, you must study the flow on how the sequence works, starting at the end instead at the beginning. You must find out how it got there by re-trace the steps. Take note that this is a pseudocode, in a way.