# call method from android phone menu button with libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to find a way to call a custom method from the phones menu button from within a libGDX screen.

Is there a way to do this. i Know that you can catch the touch with

```
Gdx.input.setCatchMenuKey(true);
```

but I have not been able to find a way to call a method.

From within the class which extends Screen I would like to have a method such as the following which is called when the phone menu key is pressed:

```
private void onPhoneMenuKeyTouch(){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Could you please add at least pseudo-code, to clarify what method and from where you are not able to call?

Comment: You can use libgdx InputProcessor, you can find code example at following question, just use Keys.MENU instead of Keys.BACK: [similar answered question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223723/in-libgdx-how-do-i-get-input-from-the-back-button)

Comment: great, thanks, if you post as an answer i will accept

Comment: Just glad to help you :) No reward is needed.

Comment: @user2145312 you can also answer your own question and accept it, so that others know it is solved.